# Why do people sometimes confuse when to use 'will' and 'would'?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, sentence-meaning

For instance, I've heard quite a lot of people saying that "I would go" when they should be pertaining to use "I will go".

Is this because colloquials have perpetuated the language; tainting the baisc roots of language?

I do understand the usage of 'will' and 'would', but I'm somewhere lost along in semantics.

Does 'will' makes your expresssion more emphatic and firm. As to where 'would' seems to lack that authority: adding more flatness to the tone?

Example,

Person A: Dude did you hear about this party tomorrow, would you swing by?

Person B: Yeah, I probably would.

Comment: Edit your question to include an example sentence using *will* and *would*, where *would* seems wrong to you.

Comment: I've included an example above.

Comment: Learners confuse them by trying to apply rules instead of reading and listening to native speakers.

Comment: What do you mean by "pertaining"?

Comment: 'Pertaining' as if in to be fit/appropriate in the context

Comment: So they should be fitting into the "I will go"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to inculde the prefix 'use'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Will" indicates a definite future plan. "Will" is a simple declaration of intention or fact. It asks for and conveys information about something that is going to happen. Will you go? Yes, I will go.

"Would" is conditional; it indicates that I would go *if* the circumstances were right -- for example, if I felt like going, or if I had nothing else to do.

There's also a possible contrast with other situations embedded in the version with "would": yes, this is a party I would go to, whereas there are other parties where I would not consider going.

When A uses "would", he/she might also be asking if B would go as a favor: would you go so I'll know someone there?

Both versions are correct, but the meanings are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Don't stress much, both of these expressions are equally sound in their own context.

Answer (score 1):

First, an answer to the title's question, "Why do people sometimes confuse when to use will and would?":
The reason why English words are often confused one for another is that our grammar is complex.

When you compare English with many other languages, you will find that verbs, when conjugated, have very distinct forms. Not so with English.

Add on top of that, will/would are auxiliary verbs (as well as homonyms and homophones of nouns), so they conjugate with their verb.

The layers of understanding and knowledge needed to properly conjugate the auxiliary verbs and main verbs require thought and effort.

Some blame education, laziness, unwillingness to learn, and other factors for why grammar is not properly learned. ([See YourDictionary.com Blog](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/style-and-usage/causes-of-poor-writing-and-communication-in-the-workplace.html)) Some are quicker to hear and then correct improper grammar, especially when they are accustomed to hearing proper English. Even monkeys have been shown to be able to do that. ([See BBC News](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/8139322.stm))

In the end, it's a complex question without a single answer.

And secondly, to answer (I corrected some issues with the sentence): "Does 'will' make your expression more emphatic and firm? 'Would' seems to lack that authority of 'will.' Does 'would add more flatness to the tone?"

As to tone, no. ([See LiteraryDevices.com's piece on Tone](https://literarydevices.net/tone/)) But what you're picking up on is that 'would' is a *conditional verb*. However, 'would' is not *merely* a conditional verb. It's used in many sections of the full and complete conjugation of 'will.'

A resource you may want to consider is located here:  https://writingexplained.org/will-vs-would-difference